# Select objects from an array of objects with an array of ids javascript

Tags: javascript

say I have a list of objects like so.

```
const list = [{id: 1, name: "foo"}, {id: 2, name: "bar"}, {id: 3, name: "baz"}]
```

And then I have a list of items I'd like to find in said list.

```
const ids = [1, 3]
```

how can I return an array of objects that match the ids found in `ids` from `list` using javascript?

heres an example of the return I'd like to see given I have [1, 3].

```
-> [{id: 1, name: "foo"}, {id: 3, name: "baz"}]
```

Thanks 
- Josh

Comment: `list.filter(({ id }) => ids.includes(id))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it via [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method, which returns new array of items, based on condition you wrote inside. I also recommend to use [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) method to check, whether your array of ids has such item:

```js
const list = [{id: 1, name: "foo"}, {id: 2, name: "bar"}, {id: 3, name: "baz"}];
const ids = [1, 3];
const newArr = list.filter(item => ids.includes(item.id));
console.log(newArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `map` and `find`:

```js
const list = [{id: 1, name: "foo"}, {id: 2, name: "bar"}, {id: 3, name: "baz"}];
const ids = [1, 3];
const newArr = ids.map(i => list.find(({id}) => i === id));
console.log(newArr);
```